# How to inActive or disable onClick of all rows in recyclerview except one row based on a particular condition?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView have several row items. Now based on a condition i need to make particular row active and rest to be disable or blur.How can i do this?

Comment: What you have tried? Where is code?

Answer (score 0):

This can be actived in different ways. I have mentioned two ways.

```
//Take a class variable inside adapter.
int activeItemIndex = 0; //first item onClick enabled initially or -1 if non selected initially.
```

Now implement the button onClick logic as below:

**Type 1:** By using condition inside onClick()

```
public void onBindViewHolder(....) {

    viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position == activeItemIndex) {
                //do what you want to code here....
            } //do nothing if position is not activeItemIndex so it will act like disable.
        }
    });
}
```

**Type 2:** By making other item's onClick() null.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(....) {
    if(position == activeItemIndex) {
        viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do what you want to code here....
            }
        });
    } else {
        viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
}
```

Now next what you have to do is that call notifyDataSetChanged() next to the code where you will use the condition for changing the value for **activeItemIndex**. So somewhere in your code there will be snippet inside onBindViewHolder() like:

```
...
//Updating active onClick item position based on condition
if(condition) {
    activeItemIndex = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
...
```

Comment: It would be good if you can comment here for how the solution helped you.